# PySpark - Como extraer información de una columna de un DataFrame de Spark en formato JSON pero del tipo String

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Me encuentro trabajando con **PySpark** y usando los DataFrame de **Spark** en el que cada row del DataFrame contiene esta información (que va a ser siempre la misma), aunque puedan variar los valores que hay dentro de "tree", "grass" y "weed".

`{tree={in_season=true, index={color=null, category=null, value=null}, display_name=Tree, data_available=false}, weed={in_season=false, index={color=null, category=null, value=null}, display_name=Weed, data_available=false}, grass={in_season=true, index={color=null, category=null, value=null}, display_name=Grass, data_available=false}}`

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es quedarme con algunos campos, como por ejemplo, de "tree", quedarme con los campos "in_season", "index -> value", "display_name", entre otros.

El dataframe tiene el siguiente esquema:

```
df2.printSchema()
```

- data: map (nullable = true)

  - key: string
  - value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
- types: string (nullable = true)
- plants: string (nullable = true)

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es usar StructType() de la siguiente manera:

```
schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([StructField("tree", StringType())]))

df3 = df2.withColumn("tree", from_json(df2.types, schema))
```

El resultado que estoy obteniendo es NULL por cada row del dataframe.

Hay alguna otra manera de hacer esto, o hay que hacerlo con el StructType de otra manera?

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola! Probaste con explode: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/ - Si podes agregar un Data Frame de ejemplo sería genial.

Comment: @jqc Muchas gracias por lo del explode. No lo conocía, y viendo que es lo que hacia explode y cambiando el formato de los datos he podido sacarlo.

Comment: Ok. Te lo pongo en la respueta para que quede. Dsp aceptala si podés.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu problema es posible que te sirva utilizar explode. Link al artículo que lo trata: [PySpark explode array and map columns to rows](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/)